# Why drag&drop does not called dropEvent?

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, draggable, qlistview

I guess no one knows about it. I've been asking the same question for 2 days, and no one answers.

I find a toDoList project about drag&drop. And I wonder Can I get the item that dragging or dropped. I'm reading the documentation for 2 days. I implement the methods.

```
protected:
    void dragEnterEvent( QDragEnterEvent *anEvent ) override;
    void dragMoveEvent( QDragMoveEvent *anEvent ) override;
    void dragLeaveEvent( QDragLeaveEvent *anEvent ) override;
    void dropEvent( QDropEvent *anEvent ) override;
```

There are 2 listviews and toolbar. I add add and remove to the toolbar.
I can drag or drop but, I can't get text of the the items dragging. This is the main code.
And I really wonder, we override the methods right. But we do not connect the methods to something. How does the method works ?

```
todolist::todolist(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::todolist)
{
    QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget(this);
        pWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: #ECF0F1");
        setCentralWidget(pWidget);

        QVBoxLayout* pMainLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
        pWidget->setLayout(pMainLayout);

        QLabel* pwTitle = new QLabel("To Do List", this);
        pMainLayout->addWidget(pwTitle);
        pwTitle->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        pwTitle->setStyleSheet("font-size: 30pt; margin: 10%;");

        QHBoxLayout* pHLayoutLabels = new QHBoxLayout();
        pMainLayout->addLayout(pHLayoutLabels);

        QLabel* plblPending = new QLabel("Pending", this);
        plblPending->setStyleSheet("font-size: 15pt;");
        pHLayoutLabels->addWidget(plblPending);

        QLabel* plblCompleted = new QLabel("Completed", this);
        plblCompleted->setStyleSheet("font-size: 15pt;");
        pHLayoutLabels->addWidget(plblCompleted);

        QHBoxLayout* pHLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
        pMainLayout->addLayout(pHLayout);

        m_pwPending = new QListView(this);
        m_pwPending->setDragEnabled(true);
        m_pwPending->setAcceptDrops(true);
        m_pwPending->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
        m_pwPending->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
        pHLayout->addWidget(m_pwPending);

        m_pwCompleted = new QListView(this);
        m_pwCompleted->setDragEnabled(true);
        m_pwCompleted->setAcceptDrops(true);
        m_pwCompleted->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
        m_pwCompleted->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
        pHLayout->addWidget(m_pwCompleted);

        m_pwPending->setModel(new QStringListModel());
        m_pwCompleted->setModel(new QStringListModel());

        m_pwPending->setStyleSheet
        ("QListView { font-size: 20pt; font-weight: bold; }"
         "QListView::item { background-color: #E74C3C; padding: 10%;"
         "border: 1px solid #C0392B; }"
         "QListView::item::hover { background-color: #C0392B }");

        m_pwCompleted->setStyleSheet
        ("QListView { font-size: 20pt; font-weight: bold; }"
         "QListView::item { background-color: #2ECC71; padding: 10%;"
         "border: 1px solid #27AE60; }"
         "QListView::item::hover { background-color: #27AE60 }");


        QToolBar* pToolBar = new QToolBar(this);
        addToolBar(pToolBar);

        m_pActAdd = new QAction(this);
            m_pActAdd->setIcon(QIcon(":/resources/add.png"));
            connect(m_pActAdd, &QAction::triggered, this, &todolist::onAdd);

            m_pActRemove = new QAction(this);
            m_pActRemove->setIcon(QIcon(":/resources/remove.png"));
            connect(m_pActRemove, &QAction::triggered, this, &todolist::onRemove);

        pToolBar->addAction(m_pActAdd);
        pToolBar->addAction(m_pActRemove);

        setAcceptDrops(true);
}

void todolist::onAdd()
{
    m_pwPending->model()->insertRow(m_pwPending->model()->rowCount());
    QModelIndex oIndex = m_pwPending->model()->index(
    m_pwPending->model()->rowCount() - 1, 0);

    m_pwPending->edit(oIndex);

}

void todolist::onRemove()
{
    QModelIndex oIndex = m_pwPending->currentIndex();
    m_pwPending->model()->removeRow(oIndex.row());
}
void todolist::dropEvent(QDropEvent* event) {
    const QMimeData* mimeData = event->mimeData();
    QString temp;
    if(mimeData->hasText()) {
        temp = mimeData->text();
    }

    QMessageBox::information(this,"x",temp);
}

void todolist::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *anEvent)
{
    anEvent->setAccepted(true);
}

void todolist::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *anEvent)
{

}

void todolist::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent *anEvent)
{

}
todolist::~todolist()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

```
QMimeData* ListModel::mimeData(const QModelIndexList& qMIndices) const {

  QMimeData* const pQMimeData = new QMimeData;
  QString qText;

  for (const QModelIndex& qMIndex : qMIndices) {
    qText += data(qMIndex, Qt::DisplayRole).toString() + "\n";
  }
  pQMimeData->setText(qText);

  std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
  draggedData = qText;
  return pQMimeData;
}
```

draggedData = qText; this line throws an error.

Comment: You described how you prepared the sink i.e. where things are dropped. You also have to prepare the source i.e. from where you intend to drag things (regardless whether the source and sink are instances of the same or different classes). Are you aware of this? Drag & Drop isn't really easy stuff but there are some valuable tutorials in the Qt doc. concerning this. Thereby, MVC widgets (`QTreeView`, `QTableView`, etc.) provide additional DnD features but still need more or less custom code on both sides to enable drag&drop.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I know it's not that easy. But I'm searching about it for 3 days. You mean I have to override dragEnterEvent? Give me some start point so, I can continue.

Comment: You have to override [dragEnterEvent()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#dragEnterEvent) for sure: _If the event is ignored, the widget won't receive any drag move events._ Nevertheless, this is something which is called on the drop site. On the drag site, you have to prepare the dragged data e.g. by providing a custom model where [mimeData()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#mimeData) is overridden. (I don't know what the default impl. does. It never was useful for my intentions.)

Comment: FYI: [Qt Doc. - Model/View Programming - Using Drag and Drop with Item Views](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat website is helpful actually however more I read, the more confused I get. Because I should override mimeData method and for this I need model mimeType. However I couldnt get the QStringListModel::mimeType. I guess I don't know C++ enough to implement DnD. Actually what I want is seemed easy. I already did the drag&drop action. I only want the text of the item that drag or drop.

Comment: I must admit, concerning `mimeTypes()`, I had some confusion as well. AFAIR, `mimeTypes()` wasn't important. Even returning an empty string list didn't have any negative effect. (I just revisited my working implementation to be sure not to say something wrong.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat As I understand, I should override mimeData() because If I wanna get the dragged data, I have to implement like which type I want to get it. Is that right ?

Comment: Re. `"...I've been asking the same question for 2 days, and no one answers"`: in a [previous (deleted) post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73358670/how-should-dragdrop-be-implemented) I added a comment suggesting you should start by reading the relevant [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/dnd.html) and [examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/examples-draganddrop.html).  Please ask yourself: do your own `drag*Event` implementations etc. look anything like those in the examples shown in the docs.?  Sorry, but there's no point in asking for help if you don't take any notice of the help given.

Comment: @G.M. I'm literally reading dnd doc and that example you wrote since this morning 8am. Time is 15:27 rn. I keep posting same question because honestly I read 5 different DnD doc today. Example project's mimeType is icon, how I can understand what should I do when I'm dragging in QStringListModel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the recommended site [Qt Doc. - Model/View Programming - Using Drag and Drop with Item Views](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views) to knit a small sample application for what OP asked.

My MCVE `testQListViewDragNDrop.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class ListModel: public QStringListModel {

  public:
    using QStringListModel::QStringListModel;

  protected:
    // for drag site
  
    // encodes dragged items (different from default).
    virtual QMimeData* mimeData(const QModelIndexList& qMIndices) const override;
    
    // for drop site

    // returns which kind of drop actions are supported.
    virtual Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const override
    {
      return Qt::MoveAction;
    }

    // checks whether certain dragged MIME data is droppable.
    virtual bool canDropMimeData(
      const QMimeData* pQMimeData, // dragged data
      Qt::DropAction action, // not evaluated
      int row, // not evaluated
      int column, // uninteresting for lists (but relevant for tables and trees)
      const QModelIndex& qMIndex) // uninteresting for lists (but relevant for trees)
      const override
    {
      return pQMimeData->hasText();
    }

    // drops dragged MIME data into model.
    virtual bool dropMimeData(
      const QMimeData* pQMimeData, // dropped data
      Qt::DropAction action, // not evaluated
      int row, // where to insert
      int column, // uninteresting for lists (but relevant for tables and trees)
      const QModelIndex& qMIndex) // uninteresting for lists (but relevant for trees)
      override;
};

QMimeData* ListModel::mimeData(const QModelIndexList& qMIndices) const
{
  QMimeData* const pQMimeData = new QMimeData;
  QString qText;
  for (const QModelIndex& qMIndex : qMIndices) {
    qText += data(qMIndex, Qt::DisplayRole).toString() + "\n";
  }
  pQMimeData->setText(qText);
  return pQMimeData;
}

bool ListModel::dropMimeData(
  const QMimeData* pQMimeData, Qt::DropAction action,
  int row, int, const QModelIndex& qMIndex)
{
  // get text from mime data
  const QString qText = pQMimeData->text().trimmed();
  if (qText.isEmpty()) return true;
  // split text into lines
  const QStringList qLines = qText.split(QChar('\n'));
  const int n = qLines.size();
  // fix row
  if (qMIndex.isValid()) row = qMIndex.row(); // dropped on row
  if (row < 0 || row > rowCount()) row = rowCount();
  // insert list into list model
  if (insertRows(row, n)) {
    for (const QString& qLine : qLines) {
      setData(index(row, 0), qLine);
    }
  }
  // done
  return true;
}

QStringList makeSampleData()
{
  QStringList qList;
  qList
    << "Read the Qt doc."
    << "Write CMakeLists.txt"
    << "Write testQListViewDragNDrop.cc"
    << "Test and Debug"
    << "Fix bugs"
    << "Test and Debug"
    << "Fix bugs"
    << "Test and Debug"
    << "Fix bugs"
    << "Test and Debug"
    << "Fix bugs"
    << "Test and Debug"
    << "Fix bugs"
    << "Write SO answer";
  return qList;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWinMain;
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("Test QListView Drag & Drop");
  qWinMain.resize(640, 480);
  QGridLayout qGrid;
  qGrid.addWidget(new QLabel("<b>To Do</b>"), 0, 0);
  qGrid.addWidget(new QLabel("<b>Done</b>"), 0, 1);
  qGrid.setRowStretch(1, 1);
  QListView qListToDo; // drag site
  ListModel qListModelToDo;
  qListModelToDo.setStringList(makeSampleData());
  qListToDo.setModel(&qListModelToDo);
  qListToDo.setDragEnabled(true); // allow drag in ToDo list
  qGrid.addWidget(&qListToDo, 1, 0);
  QListView qListDone; // drop site
  ListModel qListModelDone;
  qListDone.setModel(&qListModelDone);
  qListDone.viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true); // allow drops
  qListDone.setDropIndicatorShown(true); // adjust drop indicator
  qGrid.addWidget(&qListDone, 1, 1);
  qWinMain.setLayout(&qGrid);
  qWinMain.show();
  // run-time loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Demo Session:

[image: GIF Animation of Demo Session]

**Notes:**

- There is no custom list view necessary. &emdash; The `QListView` can be used but Drag as well as Drop have to be configured. Thereby, a `QListView` can be configured for drag *and* drop in contrast to my sample code.
- Contrary to what I recommended in comments, there is admittedly no need  to override `dragEnterEvent()` (or company). These events are already overridden in `QListView` and consult the corresponding model for drag & drop support.
- There is even no custom string list model necessary. After configuration of list views for drag & drop, it started to work with `QStringListModel` as well. I derived `QStringListModel` to demonstrate how to customize drag & drop.
- The overridden functions `mimeData()`, `canDropMimeData()`, and `dropMimeData()` are not necessary as well. Drag & drop will work even without them. (I tested this before I added them.) I don't know what MIME data is used to communicate the dragged contents. As drag site and drop site are the same widget class in my sample, it's not surprising that the dragged data can be dropped (however it's stored internally).

Comment: I think I kind of understand. I'll analyze your code by deleting line by line. You're my hero rn. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have a problem. I create listmodel class and it's working well but the problem is mimeData is ListModel method and I cant access this from another class. I declare ListModel in main .h file and tried but I cant. What should I do then ? @Scheff'sCat

Comment: Why do you want to access `mimeData()`? Usually it's `protected` as it's intended to be called internally (e.g. indirectly by `QDrag`) exclusively. That said - you still can make it `public` to make it accessible from anywhere.

Comment: Because I wanna use the mimeData text when modelChanged is triggered for MYSQL update query. And I have a database variable for whole project I passed through classes with initialize method that I wrote. @Scheff'sCat

Comment: Oh that's not the solution. Because I have to pass parameter if I wanna use it like that. I'm trying to reach the mimeData return value when methods are triggered. I add a image to show what I want

Comment: This sounds like a new question to post.